# Can be use Jstree directly in Reactjs. Is there any alternative of jstree in reactjs

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jstree

I already have the solution for taxon browser using jstree, i want to implement the jstree using reactjs, as we plan to move the website to reactjs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If somebody looking for Jstree in reactjs. Please look for this package, that will serve you well.
[rc-tree package for jstree in react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-tree)

Comment: rc-tree doesn't support drag and drop like jstree